# angularJS update inline script with model

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I need to update `datetimepicker[i]` script inside `ng-repeat` but I do not know how to do that.

`<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker{{$index+1}}'>`

work successfully and made list of

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>

<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
```

but problem is script not update from model data

```
$('#datetimepicker{{$index+1}}').datetimepicker();
```

result is

```
$('#datetimepicker{{$index+1}}').datetimepicker();
```

I want to `'#datetimepicker{{$index+1}}'` change to`'#datetimepicker1'`

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="row in game.result">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td ng-bind="row.host"></td>
    @*<td>
            <input class="form-control text-center" data-ng-model="row.dateStart" />
        </td>*@
    <td ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
        <div class="input-group w-360">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker{{$index+1}}'>
                <input data-format="yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss" ng-model="row.dateStart" type='text' class="form-control" ng-required="true" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker{{$index+1}}').datetimepicker();
                          });
            </script>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select ng-model="row.gameState"
                ng-options="c.Value as c.Text for c in game.states" class="form-control" required></select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control text-center" data-ng-model="row.hostGoals" type="number" required />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control text-center" data-ng-model="row.guestGoals" type="number" required />
    </td>
    <td ng-bind="row.guest"></td>
</tr>
```

### Update

I move my code inside controller and make html in controller

Controller - MVC

```
onlineResult.dateHtml = @"<script type=""text/javascript"">$(function () {$('#datetimepicker"+(i + 1).ToString()+ "').datetimepicker({format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'});});</script>";
```

and update view to

```
<p compile data-ng-bind-html="to_trusted(row.dateHtml)"></p>
```

My new problem is model bind in `Get` but not changed in `Post`.
When i submit form my `Get` data sent to controller not changed data

Comment: whole approach won't work....this needs to be done in custom directive. And you most likely will find an angular module for this datepicker available already

Comment: Don't put script tags in angular templates...they get stripped out and won't execute

Comment: `ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">` inside of `ng-repeat`. Worst approach ever.  Actually which controller using for this template?

Comment: @RameshRajendran why its worst approach ?

Comment: @charlietfl question updated

Comment: that is not how to do it....you use a custom directive that will expose the element and the plugin initialization code gets called inside the link function of that directive for that element

Comment: Did you even try searching for datepicker modules? there are numerous ones around..not sure about that specific datetimepicker but there are datetime modules

Comment: @charlietfl its standard bootstrap datetimepicker.

Comment: and there is probably an angular module for it. You really need to read [Thinking in angular when i have a jQuery background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) then do a search for jQuery plugins and angular directives if you don't find an angular module for that picker

Comment: @charlietfl yes thank you I will use angular version of datetime picker

Comment: some modules may just be wrappers for jquery plugins...but they simplify re-inventing the wheel

Answer (score 0):

I used angularjs directive datetimepicker

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker